# Why is this method not recursive?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, enums

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question without posting the whole code here (it's quite a bit), but I'll try my best.

I have an enum class which implements an interface. The purpose of the whole program is to represent a bunch of integer numbers in Fields. So there is a concrete class `TrueField` which is derived from abstract class `AbstractField` that has the implementation of a method called `boolean sameAs(Field that)`. That method also exists (it has to, because of the interface) in the enum class:

```
enum SimpleField implements Field{

  Empty(),Zero(0),Binary(0,1),Unsigned(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

  private Field simpleField;

  SimpleField(int... intArray){
      simpleField = new TrueField(intArray);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean sameAs(Field that){
      return that.sameAs(simpleField);
  }
}
```

Implementation from  `TrueField`:

```
public class TrueField extends AbstractField{

private final int[] intArray;

TrueField(int... thatArray){
    intArray = thatArray;
}

@Override
public int at(int index){
    if(index<0 || index>=intArray.length){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    return intArray[index];
}

@Override
public int length(){
    return intArray.length;
}
...
```

AbstractField:

```
public abstract class AbstractField implements Field{

@Override
public abstract int length();   


@Override
public boolean sameAs(Field that){
    if(that==null)
        throw new RuntimeException("that is null");

    boolean result = true;

    if(length()==that.length()){
        for(int i=0;i<length();i++){
            if(at(i)!=that.at(i))
                result = false;
        }
    }
    else
        result = false;

    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString(){

    String result = "";

    for(int i=0;i<length();i++){
        result += at(i);

        if(length()-i>1)
            result += ",";
    }

    return "["+result+"]";
}
```

}

My question is, when I do something like this in my main method:

```
Field sf = SimpleField.Binary;
Field sf2 = SimpleField.Binary;
Field tf = new TrueField(1,2);

System.out.println(sf.sameAs(sf2));
```

...obviously the method `sameAs` in the enum class gets called. But why isn't it calling itself again so it is recursive? As there is dynamic binding because of the interface the JVM sees that `sf` is the dynamic type `SimpleField.Binary` and the static type `Field`. I don't quite understand what's going on and why it isn't calling itself again. I hope I've explained my question clear enough.

Comment: Why would it call itself again? It's calling a method named `sameAs` on the object referenced by `that` (unless `that` is referencing the same object as `this`).

Comment: There are two implementations involved, but you've only shown us one of them. It would be really helpful if you'd show *both* implementations - ideally a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: wow that was quick, thanks. @JonSkeet

Comment: I edited the code in the main method, so that the object that calls sameAs is SimpleField and the argument is also SimpleField. That is what I wanted to do, and even then the program works fine without recursion which I don't understand since the parameter object is now 'SimpleField' and that parameter calls 'sameAs' again which is the method in 'SimpleField' @mbomb007

Comment: So I've taken a liberty; I've added the method to your question that you posted as an answer originally.  If this isn't correct, **please** edit your question so that it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recursive because your `sameAs` method in the `SimpleField` enum calls the `sameAs` method of the parameter object, which is *not* a `SimpleField`, it's a `TrueField`.

So the `sameAs` method is being run as declared in the `Field` class.

On further inspection, it *could* be recursive, but only if the declaration in the `TrueField` class was recursive also, *which we can see that it is not, now that this code has been added above.*

Comment: I just realized that I actually wanted to do the opposite, please look at the edited code in the main method. @mbomb007

Comment: @kimsay Thanks for posting that code. Now that we can see it, we know that it's not recursive. It calls the method contained in the other object, which compares the two and returns the boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

The method isn't recursive because it's not calling *itself*.

```
@Override
public boolean sameAs(Field that){
    return that.sameAs(simpleField);
}
```

This method is using the argument to call `sameAs`.  The argument may very well be the same enum, but it's still not calling itself.

This is an example of a simple recursive method:

```
public long factorial(int value) {
    return value == 0 ? 1 : factorial(value-1);
}
```

In this, there's no extra reference to use to call the method again; I'm just invoking it once more with a slight change in parameters.

Comment: thank you so far guys. @Makoto could you please tell me what is going on exactly step by step when it is called. I'm loosing the forrest for the trees somehow :(